# Pythonic way of generating dummy data efficiently

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, pandas, multiprocessing, dummy-data

Trying to generate a billion rows of random data on a box with below configuration, only the data creation is running on this box. **Only looking for directions on what methods can be used to improve performance.**

```
Running         : Python 2.7 
OS              : RHEL 7.5

processor       : 1 to 15
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 79
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2686 v4 @ 2.30GHz
stepping        : 1
microcode       : 0xb00002a
cpu MHz         : 2300.268
cache size      : 46080 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 16
core id         : 7
cpu cores       : 8
```

**CODE :**

```
import random
from datetime import date
import csv
import collections
from multiprocessing import Process
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta

recordCount = 100000
start_date="2017-01-01"
end_date="2017-03-31"

file1 = csv.writer(open('file1.csv', "wb"), quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
file2 = csv.writer(open('file2.csv', "wb"), quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
file3 = csv.writer(open('file3.csv', "wb"), quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

weekend = set([5, 6])

for i in range(1, recordCount):
    for date in daterange(start_dt, end_dt):
        if date.weekday() not in weekend:
            for i in range(1, random.randrange(5, 9)):          
                file1.writerow(rand_amt())
                file2.writerow(rand_amt())
                file3.writerow(rand_amt())

def rand_amt():
    amt_1 = random.randrange(0, 10000)
    amt_2 = random.randrange(0, 10000)
    amt_3 = random.randrange(0, 1000)
    amt_4 = random.randrange(0, 100)

    return amt_1, amt_2, amt_3, amt_4

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)
```

> INFO Program took: --- 44906.657975 seconds ---

The above code takes about ~13 hours for one quarter and I reckon it's due to the nested iteration.

** I tried **

> 1. Creating a list and appending to it rather than writing for each record. Write after certain iteration is completed but I didn't see a lot improvement here. I saw 1 sec improvement when I ran it for 1000 records.
> 2. Tried Multithreading / Multiprocessing, seems I didn't totally understand the diff between them. Still trying.
> 3. Tried to split them into months/quarters, but too much manual effort to track the process and concatenate the files.

What is the most recommended approach using Python for this type of problem? Is there a way to improve performance ?

Or should I be looking elsewhere?

**Requirement is to generate 10 Million Dimension Records for each day and each Dimension record should have 5-8 records in Fact Table. Ideally, there must be three facts with 5-8 Rec each in a single iteration & they should have random values.**

Comment: What are `start_dt` and `end_dt`? I think there's a couple things we can do here to speed this up, but I want to run it and profile it first for my own sake.

Comment: @MattMessersmith start_dt and end_dt is the time period for which the data have to be created. For example, if there are 1 Million clients, I will randomly generate 5 - 8 records per client per weekday per year. Instead of running for the entire year, in which case the prog might run for days. I created the start & end date so that I can run them / quarter. So there is 4 instance running parallel .

Comment: @MattMessersmith While you are profiling, any recommendation on what techniques can improve the performance? I can also explore and see if it would help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The profiler won't tell you *how* to speed your code up, but it will tell you *where* to look. I'd recommend using `cProfile`